# installing TensorFlow on the IBM power8

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, protocol-buffers

I have access to a large IBM Power8 machine, and would like to install TensorFlow on it. Naturally, I tried the quick pip install, but it failed:

```
sudo pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.6.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
tensorflow-0.6.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Storing debug log for failure in /home/pv/.pip/pip.log
```

Unfortunately, pip.log cotains little useful info.

```
/usr/bin/pip run on Sat Feb  6 17:29:34 2016
tensorflow-0.6.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 168, in from_line
    raise UnsupportedWheel("%s is not a supported wheel on this platform." % wheel.filename)
UnsupportedWheel: tensorflow-0.6.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Next thing I tried was to build TensorFlow from source. To no avail, all my attempts ended with some `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error` message, e.g.:

```
/usr/local/bin/bazel: line 86: /usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

So then I tried to compile Bazel from source, which also resulted in a similar hard error.

```
me@machine:~/bazel-0.1.5$ ./compile.sh
INFO: You can skip this first step by providing a path to the bazel binary as second argument:
INFO:    ./compile.sh compile /path/to/bazel
  Building Bazel from scratch.
Compiling Java stubs for protocol buffers...
third_party/protobuf/protoc-linux-x86_32.exe -Isrc/main/protobuf/ --java_out=/tmp/bazel.T9C83cNa/src src/main/protobuf/android_studio_ide_info.proto
scripts/bootstrap/buildenv.sh: line 63: third_party/protobuf/protoc-linux-x86_32.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
pv@sardonis:~/bazel-0.1.5$ ^C
```

I however found this link http://www.cnblogs.com/rodenpark/p/5007744.html that explains how to build the Protobuf compiler from source on the Power8 machine. This worked and after the modifications described in his other topic http://www.cnblogs.com/rodenpark/p/5007846.html I managed to at least get the compilation process started. But now it crashes with a ton of errors which each seem less severe on their own but the vast amount of them makes it look really hopeless, I posted them on http://pastebin.com/KjkseaGx for reference.

So... I'm running out of inspiration. What can I do to make TensorFlow work on the Power8 machine?

Comment: That means the binary you have is not compatible with where you are trying to run it, try build bazel from sources.

Comment: But I did! I added the explicit error message above, maybe this gives you more info? To me, it looks like I need to compile protobuf too since `third_party/protobuf/protoc-linux-x86_32.exe` is likely not the right compiler. I used the instructions of http://bazel.io/docs/install.html and I tried also with the tar.gz of the sources. So what should I do then?

Comment: Also, another thing I tried was replacing protoc-linux-x86_32.exe by a symbolic link to /usr/local/bin/protoc, which was shipped with my distribution (version is `libprotoc 3.0.0` according to `protoc --version`). That however resulted in a similar load of errors: http://pastebin.com/HN0MQiC4

Comment: I've launched a new topic about Bazel specifically here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381648/building-bazel-from-source-on-ibm-power8 it's probably best to indeed settle that part first.

Comment: IBM have prebuilt binaries for Tensorflow, torch and other deep learning platform. Instructions are available on their website.

Answer (score 3):

## Install bazel 0.2.0-ppc

```
tf@ubuntu16:~$ git clone https://github.com/ibmsoe/bazel
tf@ubuntu16:~/bazel$ git checkout v0.2.0-ppc
tf@ubuntu16:~/bazel$ ./compile.sh
```

## Install tensorflow

```
tf@ubuntu16:~$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow$ git checkout  v0.10.0rc0
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow$ git commit -m"v0.10.0rc0"
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow$ git cherry-pick ce70f6cf842a46296119337247c24d307e279fa0
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow$ git cherry-pick f1acb3bd828a73b15670fc8019f06a5cd51bd564
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow$ git cherry-pick 9b6215a691a2eebaadb8253bd0cf706f2309a0b8
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow$ ./configure
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow$ bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Here you'll encounter an error, something like this

> ERROR: /home/tf/.cache/bazel/_bazel_tf/b2f766da603b0bed56d4c1d0b178456a/external/farmhash_archive/BUILD:5:1: Executing genrule @farmhash_archive//:configure failed: bash failed: error executing command /bin/bash -c ... (remaining 1 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
>   /home/tf/.cache/bazel/_bazel_tf/b2f766da603b0bed56d4c1d0b178456a/tensorflow/external/farmhash_archive/farmhash-34c13ddfab0e35422f4c3979f360635a8c050260 /home/tf/.cache/bazel/_bazel_tf/b2f766da603b0bed56d4c1d0b178456a/tensorflow
>   /tmp/tmp.XdCPQefJyZ /home/tf/.cache/bazel/_bazel_tf/b2f766da603b0bed56d4c1d0b178456a/tensorflow/external/farmhash_archive/farmhash-34c13ddfab0e35422f4c3979f360635a8c050260 /home/tf/.cache/bazel/_bazel_tf/b2f766da603b0bed56d4c1d0b178456a/tensorflow

You'll have to edit config.guess as below to insert a stanza for ppc64le

```
tf@ubuntu16:~/.cache/bazel/_bazel_tf/b2f766da603b0bed56d4c1d0b178456a/external/farmhash_archive/farmhash-34c13ddfab0e35422f4c3979f360635a8c050260$ vi config.guess
```

```
    *:BSD/OS:*:*)
        echo ${UNAME_MACHINE}-unknown-bsdi${UNAME_RELEASE}
        exit ;;
+    ppc64le:Linux:*:*)
+      echo powerpc64le-unknown-linux-gnu
+      exit ;;
    *:FreeBSD:*:*)
        case ${UNAME_MACHINE} in
```

```
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow$ bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow$ sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow*.whl
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.runfi
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow$ mkdir _python_build
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow$ cd _python_build
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow/_python_build$ ln -s ~/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.runfiles/tensorflow/* .
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow/_python_build$ ln -s ~/tensorflow/tools/* .
tf@ubuntu16:~/tensorflow/_python_build$ python  __init__.py develop
```

Answer (score 2):

Using miniconda:

Installing miniconda:

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux--ppc64le.sh -O miniconda.sh

bash miniconda.sh
```

Accept the condition and allow conda to be added to PATH

```
rm miniconda.sh
echo export IBM_POWERAI_LICENSE_ACCEPT=yes >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

This sould add (base) on terminal. Add the correct channel as first priority

```
conda config --add default_channels https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
conda config --prepend channels https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/server/ibm-ai/conda/
```

Create environment (it is good practice not to install packages on base)

```
conda create -n ai python=3.7
conda activate ai
conda install --strict-channel-priority tensorflow-gpu
```

For more information on miniconda on IBM Power 8 and Anaconda: [IBM Source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS5SF7_1.6.1/navigation/wmlce_setupAnaconda.html) & [Anaconda Source](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux-power8/)

Comment: You might also need nvidia driver compatible with CUDA libraries. For cuda-10.2, the compatible driver can be downloaded from https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/164093/en-us. Furthermore, you will also need this workaround (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4078#issuecomment-255129832) to avoid getting error for missing libcuda.so.1 module.