# Building bazel from source on IBM power8

Tags: compilation, protocol-buffers, bazel

I have access to a large IBM Power8 machine (running Ubuntu), and would like to build Bazel on it. However, when I try to do it as their installation instructions suggest, I get:

```
me@machine:~/bazel-0.1.5$ ./compile.sh
INFO: You can skip this first step by providing a path to the bazel binary as second argument:
INFO:    ./compile.sh compile /path/to/bazel
  Building Bazel from scratch.
Compiling Java stubs for protocol buffers...
third_party/protobuf/protoc-linux-x86_32.exe -Isrc/main/protobuf/ --java_out=/tmp/bazel.T9C83cNa/src src/main/protobuf/android_studio_ide_info.proto
scripts/bootstrap/buildenv.sh: line 63: third_party/protobuf/protoc-linux-x86_32.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
pv@sardonis:~/bazel-0.1.5$ ^C
```

Clearly, part of the problem is the compiler trying the 32-bit compiler. I tried the following things to no avail.

- Replacing the `third_party/protobuf/protoc-linux-x86_32.exe` by a copy of `third_party/protobuf/protoc-linux-x86_64.exe`. This gave the same error.
- Replacing `third_party/protobuf/protoc-linux-x86_32.exe` by a symbolic link to `/usr/local/bin/protoc`, which came with my distribution (this is version `libprotoc 3.0.0` according to `protoc --version`). However, this gave a large amount of errors: http://pastebin.com/HN0MQiC4
- Following the instructions on http://www.cnblogs.com/rodenpark/p/5007744.html to compile Protobuf from source and then building Bazel with the modifications on http://www.cnblogs.com/rodenpark/p/5007846.html but this resulted in a similar large amount of errors: http://pastebin.com/KjkseaGx for reference.

So, I'm out of inspiration. How can I compile Bazel on the IBM Power8 machines?

(PS: I've posted this as a part of resolving [installing TensorFlow on the IBM power8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330084/installing-tensorflow-on-the-ibm-power8), so it's not a duplicate question, just one aspect in order to solve it stepwise.)

Comment: For starters, no x86 executable will run on the power 8, so you'll have to build protobuf for it, or do the bootstrap steps separately on x86 machine. However I do not know the details for this particular software.

Comment: I know. but that is (in both ways I tried) exactly what spit out the large amount of errors in the pastebins.

Comment: Hi I am from the Bazel team, we had many changes in our bootstrap process and the change you are referring to are not up to date, could you open an issue on Bazel's Github Issue Tracker where we can follow-up more precisely on that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installing TensorFlow on the IBM power8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330084/installing-tensorflow-on-the-ibm-power8)

Answer (score 0):

The version of protobuf you're using must match the protobuf runtime that is checked in. In this case, that's protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar [1], so you have to use the compiler version 3.0.0-beta-1.

(I work on Bazel.)

[1] https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/master/third_party/protobuf