# Tensorflow/Bazel on Power8

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to run Tensorflow on Power8. As this is not available on power, I need to build it from souce. In order to build it, I need Bazel. Bazel is not supported for the latest Ubuntu version (as far as I can see), so I need to build that as well. While building Bazel, I am getting errors (listed below).

I found an install guide for Tensorflow on Power8 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330084/installing-tensorflow-on-the-ibm-power8). This links me to a [github project](https://github.com/ibmsoe/bazel) that supports power for Bazel.

The article tells me to checkout branch v0.2.0-ppc. I then run the

```
$./compile.sh
```

This results in:

```
[50 / 392] Writing file src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/libbazel-rulERROR: /home/th/projects/incrementalDL/bazel/third_party/ijar/BUILD:16:1: C++ compilation of rule '//third_party/ijar:zip' failed: gcc failed: error executing command
```

v0.3.0-ppc results in:

```
gRPC Java plugin not found in third_party/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-java-0.13.2-linux-ppc64le.exe
```

master-with-ppc results in:

```
Protobuf compiler not found in third_party/protobuf/protoc-linux-ppc64le.exe
```

And the one which is the closest to the Bazel master brach, Power-Support, results in:

```
ERROR: gRPC Java plugin not found in third_party/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-java-0.15.0-linux-ppc64le.exe
```

System:

```
$lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
$java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a couple of private messages that pointed me in the right direction, so thank you for those. These are the steps that allowed me to build Tensorflow on Power8 (I did them without GPU support):

- Followed the requirements in this [blogpost](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/fe313521-2e95-46f2-817d-44a4f27eba32/entry/Building_TensorFlow_on_OpenPOWER_Linux_Systems?lang=en)
- Used the v0.2.0-ppc-protobuf branch from this [github](https://github.com/ibmsoe/bazel) for Bazel
- Got the bash completion for Bazel working as described [here](https://www.bazel.io/versions/master/docs/install.html#bash)
- Continued to follow the previous [blogpost](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/fe313521-2e95-46f2-817d-44a4f27eba32/entry/Building_TensorFlow_on_OpenPOWER_Linux_Systems?lang=en) to checkout tensorflow from the mentioned git places and used the recommended cherry-picks, but did not compile for GPU
- Build the pip package using

  ```
  $ bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
  ```

  as I did not want to compile for GPU
- Got an error

  ```
  ERROR: /home/th/.cache/bazel/_bazel_th/994c6fd5bf0a6c9879e74e714d455083/external/farmhash_archive/BUILD:5:1:
  configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
  ./config.guess: unable to guess system type
  ```

  Downloaded the latest of config.guess and config.sub as described in the error message:

  ```
  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD
  and
  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD
  ```

  and placed it in the directory mentioned by " lpralf commented on Jul 14 " as described at this [tensorflow github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/851), but this did not work, so I added 2 copies to ./[tensorflow-root-dir]/farmhash.BUILD (as my error indicated farmhash), right before configure is run:

  ```
      cmd = "pushd external/farmhash_archive/%s; workdir=$$(mktemp -d -t tmp.XXXXXXXXXX); cp -a * $$workdir; pushd $$workdir; cp [absolute-path-to-the-downloaded-config.guess]/config.guess .; cp [absolute-path-to-the-downloaded-config.sub]/config.sub .;./configure; popd; popd; cp $$workdir/config.h $(@D); rm -rf $$workdir;" % prefix_dir,
  ```
- ```
  $ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
  ```
- ```
  $ sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-[whatever-package-is-present].whl
  ```
- Tested with

  ```
  $ python ./tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py
  ```

  *Note that there is a tensorflow directory inside the tensorflow root dir

Comment: Even though it build, there was a non-deterministic stack-smashing error. This was due to glibc. More info [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1642390)